# Loop through class keys inside constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object

Let's say I have a gigantic class and I want to set the default values of its keys by performing some sort of logic

```
export class SomeClass {
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
    // gigantic list of key value pairs

    constructor(multiply) {
        const keys = Object.keys(this);
        keys.forEach((k, i) => keys[k] = i * multiply);
    }
```

How come `Object.keys(this)` returns an empty array? 
How come `new SomeClass()` returns an empty object?

Comment: looks like you'd prefer to use a list instead of defining parametrs one by one

Comment: Try `key = value;` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't compile properties that are not initialised. For example this:

```
class SomeClass {
    a: string
    b: number
}
```

… will compile to that JavaScript code:

```
var SomeClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function SomeClass() {
    }
    return SomeClass;
}());
```

You can try it using [TypeScript's Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html).

If you want to loop on those keys, you'll have to initialise all of their values. For example, this will work as you want.

```
class SomeClass {
    a: string = '' // Initialise to an empty string.
    b: number = 0 // Initialise to 0.

    constructor() {
      console.log(Object.keys(this)) // => ['a', 'b']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mateusz Kocz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382409/mateusz-kocz)'s answer, you can initialize the properties with `undefined` and even put the properties definitions after the constructor. The keys will be there too.

```
class NotInitialized {
    a: string;
    b: number;

    constructor() {
        logObjectKeys(this); // "NotInitialized" []
    }
}

class InitializedWithUndefined {
    a: string = undefined;
    b: number = undefined;

    constructor() {
        logObjectKeys(this); // "InitializedWithUndefined" ["a", "b"]
    }
}

class WithPropertyAfterConstructor {
    constructor() {
        logObjectKeys(this); // "WithPropertyAfterConstructor" ["a", "b"]
    }

    a: string = undefined;
    b: number = undefined;
}

new NotInitialized();
new InitializedWithUndefined();
new WithPropertyAfterConstructor();

function logObjectKeys<T>(source: T) {
    console.log(
        Object.getPrototypeOf(source).constructor.name,
        Object.keys(source));
}
```